# Como gerar um número aleatório que é armazenado no navegador em Javascript ou PHP?

Tags: php, javascript, liquibase

Eu gostaria de colocar o código de n de pedidos antes do single product summary no woo, cujo hook em PHP é: woocommerce_before_single_product_summary. Mas se alguém quiser me mostrar o código javascript eu ficaria grato também.

Este código está em linguagem liquid. Mas basicamente esse código gera um número de 333 a 1800 na página e uma vez gerado o usuário pode atualizar quantas vezes quiser e não muda. Se alguém puder me ajudar ficarei muito grato. Desculpe, só sei o básico do básico.

```
{%- atribuir mínimo = 333 -%}
{%- atribuir máx. = 1800 -%}
{%- atribuir diff = max | menos: min -%}
{%- assign random_number = "agora" | data: "%N" | módulo: diff | mais: min -%}

<span> Novo | {{ random_number }} vendidos </span>
```

Comment: Em php você pode usar [rand](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.rand). `rand(333, 1800)`.

Answer (score -2):

Você pode usar esse código de javascript abaixo para gerar um numero aleatório usando o range que você quiser, no caso eu já coloquei o seu.

```js
function getRandomIntInclusive(min, max) {
  min = Math.ceil(min);
  max = Math.floor(max);
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}
console.log(getRandomIntInclusive(333, 1800))
```

referencia MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random